# terraform-provider-vsphere winrm config reset upon clone customization

Tags: terraform

## Environment

- Vsphere 6
- VM OS = Win Server 2016
- terraform version = 0.11.7
- terraform-provider-vsphere version = 1.4.1

## Issue / Question

I've noticed that using the customization block will reset the winrm config I had preconfigured on the template.
I've attempted to work around this by configuring winrm on the fly with `run_once_command_list`, but that seems to operate as fire-and-forget...the provisioner is triggered prior to the command list execution (completion).

Any ideas?

Specific details can be found here ->
[terraform-provider-vsphere github issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-vsphere/issues/502)

Answer (score 0):

For windows 10 you can install the built-in OpenSSH server to transfer a file or use SSH.

```
provisioner "file" {
    source      = "BuildAgent1/buildAgent.properties"
    destination = "f:\\BuildAgent\\conf\\buildAgent.properties"
    connection {
      type     = "ssh"
      user     = "user"
      password = "password"
      timeout = "30m"
    }
  }
```